# Can I embed YouTube videos?

Tags: copyright, internet

Is embedding YouTube music videos on a webpage using the native iframe player illegal?

Are there issues (for instance, copyright) to be wary of?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a direct request for legal advice for a particular user.

Comment: Agreed.  @ano95: Please see the following Meta Q&A for an explanation of the problems associated with "legal advice": http://meta.law.stackexchange.com/q/13/10  You might be able to construct a more generic question that you will still find informative.

Comment: Edited, sorry about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that Google (the company that owns YouTube) [provides instructions for this](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters) it would seem they are offering a safe harbor if you follow their instructions, regardless of any other law.

Of course you should always review the Terms of Service governing the [contents](https://www.youtube.com/t/terms) and [APIs](https://developers.google.com/site-terms) you are using.